# Case not working on second input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a text based game that takes information inputted in the browser and translates it into an action and runs it. I am able to get it to work for the first answer but after it displays the outcome of the first answer it doesn't seem to load the second. Also once you submit anything all the cases show up and are appended to the screen without any input. Any idea how to fix this issue or make sure the case keeps repeating?
    [image: First step]
    [image: Second]
    [image: After hitting submit]
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lord of the Deahsticks</title>
    <link href="css/text-game.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="info">
    <h1 class="title">Lord of the Deathsticks</h1>
</div>

<div class="gameboard">
    <div class="event">
        <p>Hello this is the game!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="event">
        <p>You are awoken by a sound...You need to get up already, you're going to be late for you shift at the slave factory!</p>
    </div>

</div>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="action" name="what to do">
    <input type="submit" name="button">
</form>
<script src="js/controllers/controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/model/characters.js"></script>
<script src="js/JQuery/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/JQuery/text-game-JQuery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Main js/jquery

```
var template = function(action){
    return '<div class="event"><p>'+ action +'</p></div>'
};
var display = function(input){
    if(input !== "") {
        var html = template(input);
        $(html).appendTo('.gameboard');
    } else {
         alert("You need to imput an appropriate answer");
    }
    $('#action').val("");
    $('#mydiv').scrollTop(($('#mydiv').height()*2));
};

var main = function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var action = $('#action').val();
        var input = action.toLowerCase();
        display(action);
        interact(input);
        return false;
    });

};


$(document).ready(main);
```

Controller:

```
var where = "intro";
var wait = function(){

};
var interact = function(input) {
    switch(where) {
        case "intro":
            if (input === "stay in bed") {
                display("you sleep for 2 more hours");
                where = "police";
            } else if (input === "wake up") {
                display("You wake up and head to the slave factory");
                where = "on route";
            } else {
                display("You need to submit a valid response");
            }
        break;

        case "police":
            display("You are awaken by three slave police standing at your bed!");
            wait();
            display("Our records show this is you third offence citizen #000986642, you will now be sent for disciplinary reconditioning. Prepare to be detained.")
            wait();
            display("what will you do? -Go with them?  -Fight them?  -Try to Escape");

            if (input === "go with them") {
                display("You are escorted to the deathcamp");
                where = "deathcamp1";
            } else if (input === "fight them") {
                display("You jump out of bed and prepare for a fistfight");
                where = "fistfight";
            } else if (input === "try to escape") {
                display("you attempt to jump through your window");
                where = "window1";
            } else {
                display("You need to submit a valid response");
            }
            break;
    }
};
```

Comment: So if I have this correct, you submit the first response and it works, but it gives you all the display (story) lines immediately? But you want it to give just one (or a couple) depending on the story then be able to input more afterwards, correct?

Comment: For the first input it will only display the correct outcome (display) and will not continue and display the next question. Once I submit the form again, blank or with something it then displays the remaining case finishing with the outcome of the first possible condition (sent to deathcamp)

Comment: You just have a bit of logic error. Your code works as it is! I've included an answer. Good luck with the rest of it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea and your code works. It's just you might need to rethink some of your logic and maybe add some more error handling (if needed).

I've updated your code:

```
var interact = function(input) {
    switch(where) {
        case "intro":
            if (input === "stay in bed") {
                setTimeout( function() { display("you sleep for 2 more hours"); }, 1000);
                setTimeout( function() { display("You are awaken by three slave police standing at your bed!"); }, 3000);
                setTimeout( function() { display("Our records show this is you third offence citizen #000986642, you will now be sent for disciplinary reconditioning. Prepare to be detained."); }, 5000);
                setTimeout( function() { display("what will you do? -Go with them?  -Fight them?  -Try to Escape"); }, 7000);
                where = "police";
            } else if (input === "wake up") {
                display("You wake up and head to the slave factory");
                where = "on route";
            } else {
                display("You need to submit a valid response" + where);
            }
            break;

        case "police":
            if (input === "go with them") {
                display("You are escorted to the deathcamp");
                where = "deathcamp1";
            } else if (input === "fight them") {
                display("You jump out of bed and prepare for a fistfight");
                where = "fistfight";
            } else if (input === "try to escape") {
                display("you attempt to jump through your window");
                where = "window1";
            } else {
                display("You need to submit a valid response");
            }
            break;
    }
};
```

You want to have the output in the `stay in bed` command, that way it will only happen once. Then you use the next case to present the next output or error message if necessary. Good luck on your story!

Also you'll find `.setTimeout(function, milliseconds)` useful for your waiting logic. I've included it in the answer as well ;)

[Working sample.](https://jsfiddle.net/xnwcvqb0/)

Comment: I think I might finally be getting the hand of this! thanks again for your help!